# RxJS Buffer, how to group multi click events as stream

Tags: rxjs

> In RxJS version 2.2.26

The following code produced a stream that would emit the number of clicks (double click, triple click etc..)

```
var multiClickStream = clickStream
    .buffer(function() { return clickStream.throttle(250); })
    .map(function(list) { return list.length; })
    .filter(function(x) { return x >= 2; });
```

> In RxJS version 4.0.6

This code no longer produces the desired result.

How can I get that same functionality in RxJS 4.0.6?

[Working 2.2.26 Example](http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/4gGgs/27/)

[Broken 4.0.6 Example](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/vxjo3z8r/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throttle` was changed to `debounce` starting in RxJS 3 I believe.

There was a big debate about this way back when because the original naming scheme didn't actually match with other implementations of Rx or the actual definition.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/284

And it even managed to confuse people further down the road in the reimplementation of RxJS 5:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/480

Comment: thank you for the information... Unfortunately just replacing throttle with debounce in the above broken example doesn't seem to fix it, so perhaps there's more to it than that..

Comment: my bad, there are 3 instances of throttle in the example and I only replaced it with 1 instance.  Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Just in case someone is wondering on how to do the same thing with RxJS 5 (5.0.0-beta.10), this is how I got it working:

```
const single$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
single$
    .bufferWhen(() => single$.debounceTime(250))
    .map(list => list.length)
    .filter(length => length >= 2)
    .subscribe(totalClicks => {
        console.log(`multi clicks total: ${totalClicks}`);
    });
```

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out as I'm also learning Reactive Programming (with RxJS) so, if you see a problem with this implementation or know of a better way to do the same thing, I'll be very glad to know!

Comment: Operator `debounceTime` may be replaced by `delay`. The behavior is a little bit different: debounce restarts timer on each new click within 250ms. 
See this plunk: http://embed.plnkr.co/TCyp9wXtNkY84HCqDrbR/

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a much better way to find double clicks via RxJs:

```
var mouseDowns = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, "mousedown");

var doubleClicks = mouseDowns.timeInterval()
                             .scan<number>((acc, val) => val.interval < 250 ? acc + 1 : 0, 0)
                             .filter(val => val == 1);
```

The benefit of this is that you don't need to wait for the full 250ms to recognize the double click - if the user has only 120ms between clicks there is a noticable delay between the double click and the resulting action.

Notice, that through counting up (with .scan()) and filtering to the first count we can limit our stream to just double-clicks and ignore every fast click after that - so *click* *click* *click* will not result in two double clicks.

Comment: what is <number>?

Comment: This approach would mean that a following double click can't be registered until there is a 250ms period of no clicks e.g. if `interval=5000`, and you double click immediately, you can't click for another ~5s if you want further double clicks to be recognised.

Answer (score 6):

## Detect single or double-clicks, but not multi-clicks

Here's a solution I came up with that creates a stream of single or double clicks (not anything more, so no triple clicks). The purpose is to detect multiple double clicks in quick succession, but also to receive notifications of single clicks.

```
let click$ = Observable.fromEvent(theElement, "click");

let trigger$ = click$.exhaustMap(r =>
    click$.merge(Observable.timer(250)).take(1));
let multiclick$ = click$.buffer(trigger$).map(r => r.length);
```

The reasoning is this, we use the `buffer` operator to group clicks, and design a buffer trigger event as follows: Every time a click happens, we start a *race* between two observables:

1. A 250 msec timer
2. The original click stream

Once this race concludes (we use `take(1)` because we are only interested in the first event) we emit the buffer trigger event. What does this do? It makes the buffering stop either when a 2nd click arrives, or when 250 msec have elapsed.

We use the `exhaustMap` operator to suppress the creation of another race while one is already going on. This would otherwise occur for the 2nd click in a double-click pair.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another take (produces N doubleclicks if the user quickly clicks 2*N times):

```
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const doubleclicks = clicks.pipe(
  exhaustMap(() => clicks.pipe(takeUntil(interval(250)))),
);
```

Answer (score 4):

> This answer is inspired by @Aviad P.

I believe the following code is the right answer. It meets all these requirements.

1. It differentiates `single-click`, `double-click`, and `triple-click`.
2. No unrecognized clicks will be streamed. i.e. If you click the mouse 6 times quickly, you will get 2 `triple-clicks`. If you click 5 times, you get one `triple-click` and one `double-click`. etc
3. `triple-click` will be fired immediately, no need to wait for the whole time-window complete.
4. No clicks will be lost.
5. It's easy to make it accept `four-click`, `five-click`...

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const click$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(btn, "click");

const trigger$ =
  click$.exhaustMap(r =>
    click$
    .take(2)
    .last()
    .race(click$
      .startWith(0)
      .debounceTime(500)
      .take(1))
  );


click$
  .buffer(trigger$)
  .map(l => l.length)
  .map(x => ({
    1: 'single',
    2: 'double',
    3: 'tripple'
  }[x]))
  .map(c => c + '-click')
  .subscribe(log);

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#reset'), 'click')
  .subscribe(clearLog);

function log(message) {
  document.querySelector('.log-content').innerHTML += ('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}

function clearLog() {
  document.querySelector('.log-content').innerHTML = null;
}
.log {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.log-content {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  min-height: 2rem;
}

.log-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.7/Rx.js"></script>

<button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
<button type="button" id='reset'> Reset </button>

<div class='log' id='logpanel'>
  <div class='log-header'>
    Log:
  </div>
  <div class="log-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution: starting from a source observable, detect and propagate when this observable quickly emits the exact same value (at least) twice quickly in a row:

```
var scheduler = Rx.Scheduler.default; // replace with TestScheduler for unit tests
var events = // some observable
var doubleClickedEvents = events
  /* Collect the current and previous value */
  .startWith(null) // startWith null is necessary if the double click happens immediately
  .pairwise()
  .map(pair => ({ previous: pair[0], current: pair[1] }) 
  /* Time the interval between selections. */
  .timeInterval(scheduler)
  /* Only accept two events when they happen within 500ms */
  .filter(timedPair => timedPair.interval < 500)
  .map(timedPair => timedPair.value)
  /* Only accept two events when they contain the same value */
  .filter(pair => pair.previous && pair.previous === pair.current)
  .map(pair => pair.current)
  /* Throttle output. This way, triple and quadruple clicks are filtered out */
  .throttle(500, scheduler)
```

The difference with the provided solutions is:

- Like Wolfgang's solution, this observable will immediately emit the value at the exact moment a 'double click' happens, not after a debounce time of 500ms
- Does not needlessly accumulate the amount of clicks. If you ever need to implement 'Triple-click' behavior, then Wolfgang's solution is better. But for double click behavior, this can be replaced with startWith(null).pairwise()
- Uses throttle to hold back multiple double clicks.
- Actually propagates the values that are emitted from the original events, not just a 'signal'.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way fit better to distinguish between single / double click. (So I can get either Single-Click or Double-Click, but not both)

For double click, this handled fast double click 2*N times produce N events:

```js
Observable.prototype.doubleEvent = function(timing = 150, count = 2, evt = this) {    /// flexibility to handle multiple events > 2
   return this.exhaustMap( () =>                   /// take over tapping event,
       evt.takeUntil( Observable.timer(timing) )   /// until time up,
           .take(count-1)                          /// or until matching count.
   );
}
```

Note: argument `evt = this` make doubleEvent works with `startWith()`, to take `this` Observable correctly.

Usage:

```js
this.onTap
    .doubleEvent()
    .subscribe( (result) => console.log('double click!') );
```

For distinguish between single / double click:

```js
Observable.prototype.singleEvent = function(timing = 150) {
    return this.mergeMap(               /// parallel all single click event
        () => Observable.timer(timing)  /// fire event when time up
    );
}
Observable.prototype.singleOrDoubleEvent = function(timing = 150) {
    return this.exhaustMap( (e) =>                   /// take over tapping event
        Observable.race(                             /// wait until single or double event raise
            this.startWith(e).doubleEvent(timing, 2, this)
                .take(1).mapTo(1),
            this.startWith(e).singleEvent(timing)
                .take(1).mapTo(0),
        )
    );
}
```

Usage:

```js
this.onTap
    .singleOrDoubleEvent()
    .subscribe( (result) => console.log('click result: ', result===1 ? 'double click' : 'single click') );
```